# Python - Change Simple game code into classes with methods?

Tags: python, methods

I'm trying to do a practice assignment to help learn python yet am stuck on this. It says to create a simple Die game which asks for user input to keep playing, along with displaying results. I also need to use classes. I have been able to create it without the classes yet become stuck when transferring it to classes.

```
import random

def RollDice():
    die = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)

    faceValue = die + die2

    if die == 1:
        RollOne()
    elif die == 2:
        RollTwo()
    elif die == 3:
        RollThree()
    elif die == 4:
        RollFour()
    elif die == 5:
        RollFive()
    elif die == 6:
        RollSix()

    if die2 == 1:
        RollOne()
    elif die2 == 2:
        RollTwo()
    elif die2 == 3:
        RollThree()
    elif die2 == 4:
        RollFour()
    elif die2 == 5:
        RollFive()
    elif die2 == 6:
        RollSix()

    return faceValue

def RollOne():
    print(''' ------
|      |
|   o  |
|      |
 ------ ''')
    return

def RollTwo():
    print(''' ------
| o    |
|      |
|    o |
 ------ ''')
    return

def RollThree():
    print(''' ------
| o    |
|   o  |
|    o |
 ------ ''')
    return

def RollFour():
    print(''' ------
| o  o |
|      |
| o  o |
 ------ ''')
    return

def RollFive():
    print(''' ------
| o  o |
|   o  |
| o  o |
 ------ ''')
    return

def RollSix():
    print(''' ------
| o  o |
| o  o |
| o  o |
 ------ ''')
    return

x = 1
OverallRoll = RollDice()
print("Face value:", OverallRoll)

while x == 1:
    play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Respond with 'Yes' to continue and anything else to quit.")

    if play_again == 'Yes':
        OverallRoll = RollDice()
        print("Face value:", OverallRoll)
    else:
        quit()
```

Any tips on how to make it into classes with methods? Thank you!

Comment: Please post this question at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), f you want your code to be reviewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random


class Game:
    DIE_ASCII_ART = {1: ''' ------
|      |
|   o  |
|      |
 ------ ''', 2: ''' ------
| o    |
|      |
|    o |
 ------ '''} # Do this for all values from 1-6

    @staticmethod
    def _roll_dice() -> int:
        die = random.randint(1, 6)
        die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(Game.DIE_ASCII_ART[die])
        print(Game.DIE_ASCII_ART[die2])
        return die + die2

    @staticmethod
    def run() -> None:
        running = True
        while running:
            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Respond with 'Yes' to continue and anything else to quit.")

            if play_again == 'Yes':
                overall_roll = Game._roll_dice()
                print("Face value:", overall_roll)
            else:
                running = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game.run()
```

A few other notes about your code:
You use PascalCase in your code while the convention for Python is snake_case.
You defined alot of functions and wrote alot of if statements when a simple dictonary was enough to solve the problem.

A few notes about my code:
The methods in the `Game` class are static because there isn't a need for instance variables in the code.
I added typing annotations for improved code quality.
I changed the game loop for using a number to a boolean because that is more readble in my opinion.

Refrences:

[PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

[type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)